# GAS - Get Certain columns in 2D array based on list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to build a custom array with Google sheet data by getting certain columns in a certain order. The columns/order is set on a google sheet. The below works but I would like to make the return on row 11 more dynamic.

```
function buildArray() {
  const s = SpreadsheetApp;
  const ss = s.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test Sheet');
  const pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Paste');
  const data = sheet.getRange(1,1,10,10).getValues(); //update range
  // const headers = pasteSheet.getRange(1,1,pasteSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r){return r}).flat(Infinity); //list of headers needed in 1d array
  const colNeed = [0,9,5,6,4,7]; //array index for column numbers

  var customArray = data.map(function(r){ 
    return [r[0], r[9], r[5], r[6], r[4], r[7]]; //Would like to make this more dynamic
  })
  
  debugger;
  pasteSheet.getRange(1, 2, pasteSheet.getLastRow(), pasteSheet.getLastColumn()).clear();
  pasteSheet.getRange(1, 2, customArray.length, customArray[0].length).setValues(customArray);
  debugger;
}
```

I have tried replacing the r[0] with r[colNeed.map(...)] and also a for loop with no success.

Any ideas on how to make this work.

Here is a screenshot of the final sheet.
I just copied/pasted the header names in the first column(A) to make sure the right columns were pulled/pasted.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one using a loop to combine the data first then return. Also added the headers on top of `customArray`.

#### Code:

```
function buildArray() {
  const s = SpreadsheetApp;
  const ss = s.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test Sheet');
  const pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Paste');
  const data = sheet.getRange(1,1,10,10).getValues(); // update range
  // get headers as single array (excluding blank cells)
  // since last column of data can go beyond last row of column A
  // headers can include blank cells if there is already data present
  const headers = pasteSheet.getRange(1,1,pasteSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat().filter(Boolean); 
  // array index for column numbers
  const colNeed = [0,9,5,6,4,7]; 

  var customArray = data.map(function(r){ 
    var output = [];
    colNeed.forEach(function (col){
      output.push(r[col]);
    });
    return output;
  });

  // Add headers at the first element of customArray
  customArray.unshift(headers)

  debugger;
  pasteSheet.getRange(1, 2, pasteSheet.getLastRow(), pasteSheet.getLastColumn()).clear();
  pasteSheet.getRange(1, 2, customArray.length, customArray[0].length).setValues(customArray);
  debugger;
}
```

#### Paste:

[image: paste]

#### Test Sheet:

[image: test sheet]

#### Paste Sheet after executing `buildArray`:

[image: output]